# The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to return a list of results, however. Whenever there are no results, I receive the error message which I have posted above. However, it's strange because whenever I add the variable q instead of the return, it just returns no results instead and is fine with this. I would prefer to do it the way which I am currently doing it right now, does anybody know what is wrong with the query? Whenever I run it in LINQPad it works completely fine.

```
  public IQueryable<ClaimNumberReport> GetClaimsByClaimNumber(int ClientID, int ClaimID) {
                /*var q = */ return (from d in camOnlineDb.Details
                        join a in camOnlineDb.Areas
                            on new { a = d.ClientID, b = d.AreaID ?? 0 }
                        equals new { a = a.ClientID, b = a.AreaID }
                        where d.ClientID == ClientID

                        join r in camOnlineDb.Reasons
                            on new { a = d.ClientID, b = d.ReasonID ?? 0 }
                        equals new { a = r.ClientID, b = r.ReasonID }

                        join sd in camOnlineDb.SuppDepts
                          on new { a = d.ClientID, b = d.CategoryID ?? 0 }
                      equals new { a = sd.ClientID, b = sd.CategoryID } into sdd
                      from sd in sdd.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        join h in camOnlineDb.Headers
                            on new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID}
                        equals new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
                        where h.ClaimID == ClaimID

                        join su in camOnlineDb.Suppliers
                            on new { h.ClientID, h.SupplierID }
                        equals new {su.ClientID, su.SupplierID }

                        join cp in camOnlineDb.ClaimPacks
                            on new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
                        equals new { cp.ClientID, cp.ClaimID }

                        join rev in camOnlineDb.Reviews
                            on new { h.ClientID, h.ReviewID }
                        equals new { rev.ClientID, rev.ReviewID }

                        join revp in camOnlineDb.ReviewPeriods
                            on new { a = rev.ClientID, b = rev.ReviewPeriodID ?? 0 }
                        equals new { a = revp.ClientID, b = revp.ReviewPeriodID }

                        join st in camOnlineDb.Statuses
                            on new { a = d.ClientID, b = d.StatusID ?? 0 }
                        equals new { a = st.ClientID, b = st.StatusID }

                        join stcm in camOnlineDb.StatusCategoryMappings
                            on new { st.ClientID, st.StatusID }
                        equals new { stcm.ClientID, stcm.StatusID }

                        join stc in camOnlineDb.StatusCategories
                            on new { stcm.StatusCategoryID }
                        equals new { stc.StatusCategoryID }
                        where stc.StatusCategoryTypeID == 1

                        select new ClaimNumberReport {
                            TypeID = d.ClaimTypeID,
                            CPAttached = cp.FileName,
                            ReviewPeriodName = revp.ReviewPeriodName,
                            ClaimID = d.ClaimID,
                            Line = d.ClaimLine,
                            AccountNo = su.AccountNo,
                            SupplierName = su.SupplierName,
                            Amount = d.Amount,
                            Status = st.StatusDesc,
                            DateSent = d.DateSent,
                            DayOS = d.DaysOS,
                            NominalPeriod = d.NominalPeriod,
                            SLInvoiceNo = d.SLInvoiceNo,
                            Area = a.AreaDesc,                   
                            DebitRef = d.DebitFile,
                            DebitDate = d.JournalDate,
                            DeductDate = d.DeductDate,
                            StatusCategoryID = stc.StatusCategoryID,
                            StatusCategoryDesc = stc.StatusCategoryDesc,
                            APLReason = r.ReasonDesc,
                            ClientID = d.ClientID,
                            DeptNo = sd.DepartmentID,
                            DeptName = sd.DepartmentName,
                            Agreed = d.Agreed
                        });
                /*return q;*/
            }
```

Comment: So you are saying there is a difference between `return (from ...);` and `var q = (from ...); return q;`?

Comment: Yes, whenever I just use return I receive the error message. If I use the variable it simply states that it returns no results

Comment: "Whenever there are no results" I doubt that. There must be at least one rows for this particular error to occur. Of course you will not see that row because the query crashes. Could this be true?

Comment: My guess is you receive that because of either of your `DefaultIfEmpty` lines, but that is only a guess. Not sure with the variable q behavior change, there is not enough context given. Can you do a debug breakpoint and step into the linq source code?

Comment: @usr You are correct. I think I have found the error. DepartmentID is not used for the user which I require. It is set to a non nullable int. I have changed my query to allow for a nullable int and am currently testing it for both users. It works so far, will keep you updated

Comment: @theMayer I've tried stepping into the code but as it's classed as a single expression, it jumps right to the end

Comment: I hate LINQ where it's used for relational DB queries (btw I like typed queries anyway). LINQ was meant to be an OOP query language and this query associates objects by ID :(

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer he seems to have no choice because the join conditions do not lend themselves to being mapped as navigation properties, I think. Maybe he can partially rewrite them to use navigation props.

Comment: @usr yeah... my point is that LINQ creates the false desire of composing SQL using a C# integrated syntax, while LINQ isn't meant to emulate SQL itself but who does it is the LINQ to Entities provider under the hoods....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused by a situation where the query result type has a column/property of non-nullable type but the generated query results in a `NULL` value.

This could be considered a bug or not. It is hard to see what the L2S team should have done differently here. I think they should have added a better error message. This bug is insidious because it sometimes only strikes in production under unusual data...

Your left join (`sd`) seem not to match and one of the `sd.*` properties that you select must be an `int`. Solve that like this:

```
 DeptNo = (int?)sd.DepartmentID, //Cast to nullable
```

---

`d.CategoryID ?? 0`

What are you doing here? This seems to be a way to make the join compile. It's better to use:

```
                    join r in camOnlineDb.Reasons
                        on new { a = d.ClientID, b = (int?)d.ReasonID }
                    equals new { a = r.ClientID, b = (int?)r.ReasonID }
```

This cast makes the anonymous type signatures compatible. The generated SQL should now be faster. If you say `x ?? 0` that converts to `COALESCE(x, 0)` which can prevent index use and such.